# How to use a predefined view (nib) in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xib, nib

My list consists of card views with an image and some text fields, all of which have a complex layout. This card is to be reused in the detail view, so containing it inside a `UITableViewCell` layout and then calling `UITableView.registerNib()` doesn't seem to work for me. I'd like to know the cleanest way to reuse the view I created in the NIB-file as both a list item and a part of my detail screen, while keeping as much of the view logic such as constraints and style in the NIB-file.

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Compiler error? Runtime exception? Wrong result? – And where is your code?

Comment: It does work, but didn't quite feel right and I thought there must be a better way. I'm satisfied with Matt's answer though, easy way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to know the cleanest way to reuse the view I created in the NIB-file as both a list item and a part of my detail screen

Do exactly what you're already doing: Use a nib (a *.xib* file) containing just one view, the UITableViewCell as designed, and register that nib with the table view - exactly the thing you say "doesn't seem to work for you". It *does* work. So now all your table rows consist of copies of this table view cell.

But there's the trick. When you want to show the view elsewhere, load the nib manually, pull out the view (the UITableViewCell), *pull out its `contentView`*, and add it as a subview to your interface.

```
// substitute correct name of xib file here
let arr = UINib(nibName: "MyTableViewCell", bundle: nil).instantiateWithOwner(
    nil, options: nil)
let tvc = arr[0] as! UITableViewCell
let v = tvc.contentView // now it's a normal view! customize as needed
v.frame.origin = CGPointMake(100,100) // or whatever
self.view.addSubview(v) // and plop it into the interface! voilà!
```